# APACHE PIG CAN'T LOAD BAG

Tags: load, apache-pig, bag

I have a file test.txt with the following bags:

```
{(es,1),(de,1),(ps,1),(ro,1),(so,1)}
{(es,1),(de,1),(it,2),(no,1),(ps,1),(ro,1),(so,1)}
{(es,1),(de,1),(so,1)}
```

I want to load them in Pig

```
A = LOAD 'test.txt' as (language_bag: bag{t: (a:chararray,f:int)});
```

And I obtain the following error.

> [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   mismatched input ';' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
>
> Details at logfile:
>   /homes/ruthgavi/Projects/Conferences/PigScripts/pig_1426528460732.log

Can somebody help me figure out what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: Are you sure you are using exactly this code? It works fine for me with your provided input data.

Comment: You are right. I was not using exactly this code. For a reason, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

may be it is helpful.

```
 A = LOAD 'test.txt' as (language_bag: bag {t: tuple(a:chararray,f:int)});

 C = foreach A generate language_bag.a, language_bag.f;

 dump C;
```

Comment: Thank you sravan, it works! My problem was that I was reading other columns as well ....and for a reason I dont know, if I add each field in a separate line, it doesn't work...if I add the bag in the same line, it works. Weird.